# Xamarin.Forms: Remove Square marker from HoloCircularProgressBar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-progressbar

I am implementing Xamarin.Forms-Android-CustomProgressBar of jamesmontemagno:-

https://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-controls-in-xamarin-forms-on-android/

How to remove the square marker from the progress bar when it starts, I don't want the square marker.

I tried `IsMarkerEnabled` property but it only removed the starting marker point from the progress bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to modified the [source](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/src/MonoDroidToolkit/HoloCircularProgressBar.cs) of that control to remove the square marker as it is hardcoded and not optional.

```
//draw the thumb square at the correct rotated position
canvas.Save();
canvas.Rotate(progressRotation - 90);
//rotate the square by 45 degrees
canvas.Rotate(45, thumbPosX, thumbPosY);
var rect = new RectF();
rect.Left = thumbPosX - thumbRadius / 3.0f;
rect.Right = thumbPosX + thumbRadius / 3.0f;
rect.Top = thumbPosY - thumbRadius / 3.0f;
rect.Bottom = thumbPosY + thumbRadius / 3.0f;
canvas.DrawRect(rect, thumbColorPaint);
canvas.Restore();
```

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/src/MonoDroidToolkit/HoloCircularProgressBar.cs#L286

Comment: How can I specify the Gradient color to show multiple color.

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi You can create a `SweepGradient` and apply that to the `progressColorPaint.Shader` :  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SweepGradient.html Search SO, there are a number of question/answers, in Java of course, but easily ported to C#